# Executar um Schedule do Laravel a cada minuto?

Tags: laravel, scheduler, agendamento, laravel-5.3

Estou utilizando o `Laravel 5.3` e gostaria de executar uma tarefa a cada minuto, dentro da tarefa vou colocar algumas verificações, a questão é fazer ela ser executada a cada minuto.

*Fiz o seguinte no App\Kernel:*

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();

        $schedule->call(function () {
            return redirect('/contas');
        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

*Para criar o `cron` executei:*

```
php /app/console/Kernel.php schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Porém nada acontece. Preciso fazer mais alguma coisa para funcionar?

Comment: Se não criar o cronjob (linux) ou schedtask (windows), isso nunca vai rodar. Consulte a documentação para entender como funciona: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

Comment: a única coisa que a documentação fala é para executar * * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1, fiz isso mas nada :/

Comment: vou especificar

Comment: @DanielOmine está especificado na pergunta

Comment: @DanielOmine É a primeira vez que tento mexer com schedule, então estou bem perdido kkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o login no servidor com usuário com permissões para criar agendamentos.
Para isso pode usar SSH (console) ou usar recursos de ferramentas de gerenciamento de sites como Plesk, CPnel, etc.

Via console (SSH), após fazer login, execute

```
crontab -e
```

Isso abrirá o arquivo de agendamentos do usuário logado.

Para o seu caso, deve criar um agendamento que execute a cada minuto. Adicione algo como isso:

```
1 * * * * php /caminho/completo/do/script.php
```

<sub>Para iniciar a edição, pressione a tecla "I". Depende da distribuição linux e do editor de texto.</sub>

Salve a alteração do arquivo

```
(pressione) ESC
(digite) :wq
(pressione) ENTER
```

<sub>As letras wq significam "**w**rite" e "**q**uit".</sub>

Para certificar-se de que está mesmo agendado, execute

```
crontab -l
```

Será exibido uma lista de agendamentos.

Contudo, isso ainda não garante muita coisa. Se houver algum erro no caminho do arquivo ou falha no script do arquivo, não conseguirá saber se não existir um log, monitoramento, etc.

Para ver se o caminho está correto, execute no console

```
php /caminho/completo/do/script.php
```

E veja o que acontece. Para testar, coloque um `echo time();` no final ou coloque um `mail()` para enviar um email, `file_put_contents()` para criar um arquivo, enfim. Invente o que for conveniente para testes.

Usando um gerenciador como Plesk, CPanel, etc, terá uma página para criar agendamentos de forma mais amigável sem precisar usar um console.

Normalmente apenas digitará o mesmo comando

```
1 * * * * php /caminho/completo/do/script.php
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No CPanel é similar a isso. As imagens são ilustrativas.

Comment: Infelizmente sou obrigado a desenvolver esse projeto no Windows, mas usando sua logica criei um bat para executar um command que roda o schedule, o único problema é que a cada 5 minutos abre um lindo prompt de comando :'), mas vou executar na mão para desenvolver e crio o cron no servidor na hora de mandar para producao, valeu :)

Comment: basta adicionar o comando para rodar em background....  assim não abrirá a janela..

Comment: @FelipePaetzold tem como rodar sem problemas no windows também. Outra hora posto a resposta.